# Java Soap Services: Add non-persistent result field based on a persistent one

Tags: java, web-services, soap

So I need to add a new field to a SOAP service response. The thing is that the field has to take the value from a persistent field. I cannot add that persistent field directly. The persistent field returns a "Calendar" instance, which is, in fact, a DATETIME from MySQL. The current object uses the XmlAdapter.

I did something like this:

```
class SomeClassImpl extends SomeClass
{
    @Transient
    @XmlSchemaType(name="someDate")
    private String someDate;

    ...

    public void defSomeDate()
    {
        this.someDate = this.getPersistentDate().toString();
    }

    public String retSomeDate()
    {
        return this.someDate();
    }
}
```

The new field appears in the soap result, but the value is an exception, which I don't remember right now and I am not able to reproduce it now.

How would you do this? Is it possible to annotate a method instead of the member so it appears in the  SOAP result? If yes, how would an annootation would look like?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the following piece of code:

```
@XmlSchemaType(name="someDate")
```

There "name" parameter should be one of the standard data types for xml. In this case, because it contains the date and the time, it should be '`dateTime`'. It could also be a `string`, but declaring it as dateTime makes the field more restrictive. Therefore, the correct annotation is:

```
@XmlSchemaType(name="dateTime")
```

With the date and time in mind, the second observation is that `private String someDate;` should be `private CalendarsomeDate;`, to be consistent and also for the actual code to work.

Annotating the methods is not required. Simply annotating the member/property is enough and as long as the member/property is set somewhere at runtime.

I hope this would be helpful for someone else too. It took me few hours to get this, but now I know how to proceed in the future.